# Unit tests in C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I'm doing a project in C++ in my University and we need to unit test our classes. The tests are pretty straight-forward - we don't have any "problematic" classes that deal with databases, GUI, web stuff, etc. It's just a command line program.

What is a good unit-testing framework to use that is as simple as possible? Please provide a short example of a test in that framework.

**EDIT**: I see there are some answers, so I want to add another question: Where do I put the test methods? Are they declared in a different file? Where would that file be? How do I run all tests?

Comment: Cunit http://cunit.sourceforge.net/documentation.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Boost.  Hands down.

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE my_tests // use once per test program
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( case_x )
{
  ....
  BOOST_CHECK( ... boolean expression ... );
  BOOST_etc...etc...
}
```

Comment: Can you please give some more details on where to put this file, is it `.cpp` or `.h`, etc?

Comment: It is .cpp - "superfluous junk to fill comment requirements"

Comment: how do I compile it? With a different makefile? What should be in the makefile? Is there anything I need to code except the test cases? Is it an executable? Does it run the test on compilation?

Answer (score 5):

There're many, quite similar. My prefered one is [Boost.Test](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/test/doc/html/index.html) library. It can be complicated if you need but also extremely simple for simple cases. e.g. the simplest possible case looks like:

```
#include <boost/test/minimal.hpp>

int add( int i, int j ) { return i+j; }

    int test_main( int, char *[] )             // note the name!
    {
        // six ways to detect and report the same error:
        BOOST_CHECK( add( 2,2 ) == 4 );        // #1 continues on error
        BOOST_REQUIRE( add( 2,2 ) == 4 );      // #2 throws on error
        if( add( 2,2 ) != 4 )
          BOOST_ERROR( "Ouch..." );            // #3 continues on error
        if( add( 2,2 ) != 4 )
          BOOST_FAIL( "Ouch..." );             // #4 throws on error
        if( add( 2,2 ) != 4 ) throw "Oops..."; // #5 throws on error

        return add( 2, 2 ) == 4 ? 0 : 1;       // #6 returns error code
    }
```

This example uses the [Minimal Testing Facility](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/test/doc/html/minimal.html).

Comment: If there is no good reason to do otherwise, you should link to the most recent version of Boost, which is 1.45.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: do you know if there's a version-independent link to Boost docs? Cos I didn't find one, and I would like to avoid updating links to all Boost-related answers when Boost releases a new version.

Comment: @AndyT: If you replace the version number in the link with `release` it will always resolve to the most recent version.

Answer (score 3):

[Google Test](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) is excellent. I like the actual writing of the tests a bit less than Boost (boost's UTF is EXCELLENT), but it does produce pretty console logs with colors and such on both Windows and most POSIX platforms.

Comment: And there’s a handy GUI for it called [Guitar](http://code.google.com/p/gtest-gbar/).

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://gamesfromwithin.com/exploring-the-c-unit-testing-framework-jungle) has a good overview of various unit testing options when you are programming in C++.

Comment: The problem with this article is that it's quite out of date. Google test, for example, isn't even considered, and several of complaints against each of the respective testing frameworks have been solved.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, [UnitTest+](http://unittest-cpp.sourceforge.net/)+ is what you are looking for:

> UnitTest++ is a lightweight unit
>   testing framework for C++.
>
> It was designed to do test-driven
>   development on a wide variety of
>   platforms. Simplicity, portability,
>   speed, and small footprint are all
>   very important aspects of UnitTest++.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "UnitTest++.h" 

TEST( HelloUnitTestPP )
{
   CHECK( false );
} 

int main( int, char const *[] )
{
   return UnitTest::RunAllTests();
}
```